# Oracle cursor in update procedure. Identifier must be declared

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I'm writing stored procedure for inserting (updating) REAL_START_DATE in TEST_SENDING_BOX_TABLE but getting my cursor "identifier must be declared exception"

```
PROCEDURE IN_SENDBOX_WORK_REALSTART (id_work TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.ID_SENDING_BOX_WORK%TYPE, real_start TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.REAL_START_DATE%TYPE) IS
CURSOR cur_work (id_w number) is 
      SELECT * FROM TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK 
      WHERE  ID_SENDING_BOX_WORK=id_w 
      FOR UPDATE OF REAL_START_DATE;
rec_to_mod TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  open cur_work(id_work);
  fetch сur_work into rec_to_mod;//Error(83,10): PLS-00201: identifier 'СUR_WORK' must be declared
  UPDATE TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK //Error(87,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
  SET REAL_START_DATE=real_start
  WHERE CURRENT OF cur_work;
  close сur_work;  //Error(87,10): PLS-00201: identifier 'СUR_WORK' must be declared
END IN_SENDBOX_WORK_REALSTART;
```

However this similar procedure works flawlessly.

```
PROCEDURE IN_or_UP_SENDBOX_DEMOUNTDATE(id_sendbox TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY.ID_SENDING_BOX%TYPE, p_demount TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY.DEMOUNT_DATE%TYPE) IS
cursor send_box (id_sendbox number) is 
      SELECT * FROM TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY 
      WHERE  ID_SENDING_BOX=id_sendbox
      FOR UPDATE OF DEMOUNT_DATE;
rec_to_mod TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  open send_box(id_sendbox);
  fetch send_box into rec_to_mod;
     UPDATE TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY
     SET DEMOUNT_DATE=p_demount
     where  CURRENT OF send_box;
  close send_box;
END IN_or_UP_SENDBOX_DEMOUNTDATE;
```

package TEST_DB_MOD_PKG

```
create or replace PACKAGE TEST_DB_MOD_PKG is

PROCEDURE INSERT_OBJ (p_idobj TEST_OBJ.ID_OBJ%TYPE, p_idobjtype TEST_OBJ.OBJ_KIND%TYPE);

PROCEDURE INSERT_SENDBOX (p_idsendingbox TEST_SENDING_BOX.ID_SENDING_BOX%TYPE, p_idsendboxmodel TEST_SENDING_BOX.ID_SENDING_BOX_MODEL%TYPE,
         p_dateofman TEST_SENDING_BOX.DATE_OF_MANUFACTURE%TYPE,p_serialnum TEST_SENDING_BOX.SERIAL_NUMBER%TYPE);

PROCEDURE INSERT_DEFECT(p_iddef TEST_DEFECTIVENESS.ID_DEFECTIVENESS%TYPE, p_idsendbox TEST_DEFECTIVENESS.ID_SENDING_BOX%TYPE,
         p_defkind TEST_DEFECTIVENESS.DEFECTIVENESS_KIND%TYPE,p_com TEST_DEFECTIVENESS.COMMEN%TYPE, 
         p_start TEST_DEFECTIVENESS.START_DATE%TYPE, p_end TEST_DEFECTIVENESS.END_DATE%TYPE);

PROCEDURE INSERT_SENDBOX_HISTORY(p_idobj TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY.ID_OBJECT%TYPE, p_idsendbox TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY.ID_SENDING_BOX%TYPE,
         p_mount TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY.MOUNT_DATE%TYPE);

PROCEDURE INSERT_OBJ_ATTR_VAL(p_idobjattr TEST_OBJ_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.ID_OBJ_ATTRIBUTE%TYPE, p_idobj TEST_OBJ_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.ID_OBJ%TYPE,
         p_val TEST_OBJ_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.VAL%TYPE);

PROCEDURE INSERT_WORK_ATTR_VAL(p_idworkattr TEST_WORK_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.ID_WORK_ATTRIBUTE%TYPE, p_idwork TEST_WORK_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.ID_WORK%TYPE,
         p_val TEST_WORK_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.VAL%TYPE);

PROCEDURE INSERT_SENDBOX_WORK(p_idwork TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.ID_SENDING_BOX_WORK%TYPE, p_id TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.ID_SENDING_BOX%TYPE,
         p_idworkkind TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.ID_WORK_KIND%TYPE,p_idworker TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.ID_WORKER%TYPE,
         p_start TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.START_DATE%TYPE,p_end TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.END_DATE%TYPE);

PROCEDURE INSERT_OBJ_WORK(p_idwork TEST_OBJ_WORK.ID_OBJ_WORK%TYPE, p_id TEST_OBJ_WORK.ID_OBJ%TYPE,
         p_idworkkind TEST_OBJ_WORK.ID_WORK_KIND%TYPE,p_idworker TEST_OBJ_WORK.ID_WORKER%TYPE,
         p_start TEST_OBJ_WORK.START_DATE%TYPE,p_end TEST_OBJ_WORK.END_DATE%TYPE);

PROCEDURE IN_or_UP_SENDBOX_DEMOUNTDATE(id_sendbox TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY.ID_SENDING_BOX%TYPE, p_demount TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY.DEMOUNT_DATE%TYPE);

PROCEDURE IN_SENDBOX_WORK_REALSTART (id_work TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.ID_SENDING_BOX_WORK%TYPE, real_start TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.REAL_START_DATE%TYPE);

END;
```

PACKAGE BODY TEST_DB_MOD_PKG

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY TEST_DB_MOD_PKG IS

PROCEDURE INSERT_OBJ (p_idobj TEST_OBJ.ID_OBJ%TYPE, p_idobjtype TEST_OBJ.OBJ_KIND%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TEST_OBJ("ID_OBJ", "OBJ_KIND") VALUES (p_idobj, p_idobjtype);
END INSERT_OBJ;

PROCEDURE INSERT_SENDBOX (p_idsendingbox TEST_SENDING_BOX.ID_SENDING_BOX%TYPE, p_idsendboxmodel TEST_SENDING_BOX.ID_SENDING_BOX_MODEL%TYPE,
         p_dateofman TEST_SENDING_BOX.DATE_OF_MANUFACTURE%TYPE,p_serialnum TEST_SENDING_BOX.SERIAL_NUMBER%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TEST_SENDING_BOX (ID_SENDING_BOX, ID_SENDING_BOX_MODEL,DATE_OF_MANUFACTURE,SERIAL_NUMBER)
  VALUES (p_idsendingbox , p_idsendboxmodel, p_dateofman, p_serialnum);
END INSERT_SENDBOX ;

PROCEDURE INSERT_DEFECT(p_iddef TEST_DEFECTIVENESS.ID_DEFECTIVENESS%TYPE, p_idsendbox TEST_DEFECTIVENESS.ID_SENDING_BOX%TYPE,
         p_defkind TEST_DEFECTIVENESS.DEFECTIVENESS_KIND%TYPE,p_com TEST_DEFECTIVENESS.COMMEN%TYPE, 
         p_start TEST_DEFECTIVENESS.START_DATE%TYPE, p_end TEST_DEFECTIVENESS.END_DATE%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TEST_DEFECTIVENESS (ID_DEFECTIVENESS, ID_SENDING_BOX,DEFECTIVENESS_KIND,COMMEN,START_DATE,END_DATE)
  VALUES (p_iddef , p_idsendbox, p_defkind, p_com,p_start,p_end);
END INSERT_DEFECT ;

PROCEDURE INSERT_SENDBOX_HISTORY(p_idobj TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY.ID_OBJECT%TYPE, p_idsendbox TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY.ID_SENDING_BOX%TYPE,
         p_mount TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY.MOUNT_DATE%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY (ID_OBJECT,ID_SENDING_BOX,MOUNT_DATE)
  VALUES (p_idobj, p_idsendbox,p_mount);
END INSERT_SENDBOX_HISTORY ;

PROCEDURE INSERT_OBJ_ATTR_VAL(p_idobjattr TEST_OBJ_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.ID_OBJ_ATTRIBUTE%TYPE, p_idobj TEST_OBJ_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.ID_OBJ%TYPE,
         p_val TEST_OBJ_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.VAL%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TEST_OBJ_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE (ID_OBJ_ATTRIBUTE,ID_OBJ,VAL)
  VALUES (p_idobjattr , p_idobj,p_val);
END INSERT_OBJ_ATTR_VAL ;

PROCEDURE INSERT_WORK_ATTR_VAL(p_idworkattr TEST_WORK_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.ID_WORK_ATTRIBUTE%TYPE, p_idwork TEST_WORK_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.ID_WORK%TYPE,
         p_val TEST_WORK_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.VAL%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TEST_WORK_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE(ID_WORK_ATTRIBUTE,ID_WORK,VAL)
  VALUES (p_idworkattr , p_idwork,p_val);
END INSERT_WORK_ATTR_VAL ;

PROCEDURE INSERT_SENDBOX_WORK(p_idwork TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.ID_SENDING_BOX_WORK%TYPE, p_id TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.ID_SENDING_BOX%TYPE,
         p_idworkkind TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.ID_WORK_KIND%TYPE,p_idworker TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.ID_WORKER%TYPE,
         p_start TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.START_DATE%TYPE,p_end TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.END_DATE%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK(ID_SENDING_BOX_WORK,ID_SENDING_BOX,ID_WORK_KIND,ID_WORKER,START_DATE,END_DATE)
  VALUES (p_idwork , p_id,p_idworkkind,p_idworker,p_start,p_end );
END INSERT_SENDBOX_WORK;

PROCEDURE INSERT_OBJ_WORK(p_idwork TEST_OBJ_WORK.ID_OBJ_WORK%TYPE, p_id TEST_OBJ_WORK.ID_OBJ%TYPE,
         p_idworkkind TEST_OBJ_WORK.ID_WORK_KIND%TYPE,p_idworker TEST_OBJ_WORK.ID_WORKER%TYPE,
         p_start TEST_OBJ_WORK.START_DATE%TYPE,p_end TEST_OBJ_WORK.END_DATE%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TEST_OBJ_WORK(ID_OBJ_WORK,ID_OBJ,ID_WORK_KIND,ID_WORKER,START_DATE,END_DATE)
  VALUES (p_idwork , p_id,p_idworkkind,p_idworker,p_start,p_end );
END INSERT_OBJ_WORK;

PROCEDURE IN_or_UP_SENDBOX_DEMOUNTDATE(id_sendbox TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY.ID_SENDING_BOX%TYPE, p_demount TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY.DEMOUNT_DATE%TYPE) IS
cursor send_box (id_sendbox number) is 
      SELECT * FROM TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY 
      WHERE  ID_SENDING_BOX=id_sendbox
      FOR UPDATE OF DEMOUNT_DATE;
rec_to_mod TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  open send_box(id_sendbox);
  fetch send_box into rec_to_mod;
     UPDATE TEST_SENDING_BOX_HISTORY
     SET DEMOUNT_DATE=p_demount
     where  CURRENT OF send_box;
  close send_box;
END IN_or_UP_SENDBOX_DEMOUNTDATE;

PROCEDURE IN_SENDBOX_WORK_REALSTART (id_work TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.ID_SENDING_BOX_WORK%TYPE, real_start TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK.REAL_START_DATE%TYPE) IS
cursor cur_work (id_work number) is 
      SELECT * FROM TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK 
      WHERE  ID_SENDING_BOX_WORK=id_work 
      FOR UPDATE OF REAL_START_DATE;
rec_to_mod TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  open cur_work(id_work);
  fetch сur_work into rec_to_mod;
  UPDATE TEST_SENDING_BOX_WORK
  SET REAL_START_DATE=real_start
  WHERE CURRENT OF cur_work;
  close сur_work;
END IN_SENDBOX_WORK_REALSTART;

END TEST_DB_MOD_PKG;
```

[link to screenshot](http://imageshack.com/a/img716/4760/038o.png)

Comment: Both procs appears almost identical to my eyes, but for the cursor name! Strange!!

Comment: So, the declaration part didnt show up in the compiler error?

Comment: @OracleUser, Nope, there is no error. maybe this problem is related to table privileges?

Comment: Yup in that case, declare part itself would throw error, thats why asked..

Comment: @OracleUser, but i'm using SYSTEM account. Does SYSTEM have all privileges?

Comment: @AyratBadykov - you should **not** be creating your own objects in the `system` schema. But it doesn't explain this. Are you sure line 83 of your package is actually this procedure? Wondering if you've copied and pasted these and left the wrong name somewhere else.

Comment: @Alex Poole, Yes, I'm sure. I added my package declaration and package body. Is there something wrong with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is actually correct, but it's rather subtle. The names are not the same. The declaration, `open` and `current of` have one name; the `fetch` and `close` have something very slightly different. You can see that if you do a find in your browser and search for `cur_work`, particularly if it does highlighting; with your full code there are 6 matches instead of 10.

So, what's the difference? Here's a dump of the five references:

```
select dump('cursor cur_work') from dual;
select dump('open cur_work') from dual;
select dump('fetch сur_work') from dual;
select dump('OF cur_work') from dual;
select dump('close сur_work') from dual;
```

... adjusted so the space before the variable names is aligned.

```
 Typ=96 Len=15: 99,117,114,115,111,114,32,99,117,114,95,119,111,114,107 
        Typ=96 Len=13: 111,112,101,110,32,99,117,114,95,119,111,114,107 
     Typ=96 Len=15: 102,101,116,99,104,32,209,129,117,114,95,119,111,114,107 
                  Typ=96 Len=11: 79,70,32,99,117,114,95,119,111,114,107 
     Typ=96 Len=15: 99,108,111,115,101,32,209,129,117,114,95,119,111,114,107
```

The character immediately after the space is `99` for three of them, and `209,129` for the other two. The `99` is actually `c` as you'd expected. The other is, [according to this](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024&number=128&utf8=dec), `U+0441`, 'Cyrillic small letter es', which renders as `с`. So you're mixing Latin and Cyrillic characters that just happen to look the same.

Retype the variable name in the `fetch` and `close` statements and it'll compile OK. (But preferably not in the `system` schema...)

Comment: There aren't enough words to describe my gratitude!

Comment: Alex, how did you ever find it.??!! Cool :)